# asp.net core RC2 image does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What I am trying to do is to display an image from web root folder and this is the way I am trying to do it:

The following class is just experimental and is just and example for me to try it out. For now there is only one image in the folder that is being read from.
As well the rootPath is taken from: `_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath`

```
 public class GetRandomImageForGalleryView : IGetRandomImageFromFolder
    {
        private string rootPath;
        public GetRandomImageForGalleryView(string rootPath)
        {
            this.rootPath = rootPath;
        }
        public string[] getImage()
        {
            return ReadPhotosFromDirectory();
        }
        private string[] ReadPhotosFromDirectory()
        {

            string[] fileLocations = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath+"\\lib\\Images\\Nature");
            return fileLocations;
        }
    }
```

And this is the way I am trying to display it:

```
@model IGetRandomImageFromFolder
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Gallery";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @{
            foreach (string item in Model.getImage())
            {
                <img src="@item" alt="Image" />
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

However there is no output, even if I change it to `<img src="@Url.Content(item)" alt="Image" />` Still nothing is happening.

If I just output `@item` it will display the path to the image.
The  `app.UseStaticFiles();` has been added as well.

So my question is what am I doing wrong, am I missing something? And how to do it properly?

Comment: Does the HTML get generated properly? Does the browser make a request to retrieve the image if you watch the network tab in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @mason well the request is marked red and is said to be blocked, if it makes sense. Btw thank you for saying something new, never thought about it.

Comment: It's marked in red, but what's the error code? And did you make sure the URL to the image is correct? If you copy that URL and try to navigate there directly, do you reach the image?

Comment: @mason if I specify it like this:`<img src="~/lib/Images/Nature/download.jpg" alt="Image" />` it works. So my assuptions are that something is wrong with the path that the `_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` is providing, am I correct? error code? - I cannot see anywhere in the developer tools error code.

Comment: @mason managed to solve it in a different way will ask in a different section if it is the correct way. Thank you for your response and the lesson where to look at.

Answer (score 6):

Create a folder for images in wwwroot folder
 and you can access image with this

```
<img src="~/images/123.jpg" />
```

or using url.content

```
  <img src='@Url.Content("~/images/123.jpg" )'/>
```

Comment: wwwroot.  Spent hours on something so simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It allows only files under wwwroot folder. So underneath path only has to mention. Attached example snapshot.
[image]